# What sense of 'yet' has been used in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> At the end of Neville's interview, Harry had the impression that Slughorn was reserving judgement on Neville, **yet** to see whether he had any of his parents' flair.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-blood Prince</sub>

I'm not quite sure what sense of 'yet' has been used here. It doesn't sound like a 'but'. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, "yet" means that "**still**".
Slughorn still had to confirm if Neville was as courageous as his parents or not.